# Product page problem with full page cache

Tags: magento-enterprise, error, full-page-cache

First problem: Product page not showing anything

- Main site: postme.com.my
- Category page: postme.com.my/promotions
- Sub-category page: postme.com.my/promotions/deepavali.html
- Product page: postme.com.my/promotions/deepavali/deepavali-hampers-4.html

Here is the background of our issue. Both apps and database server's specs are as below:

- Magento Enterprise 1.10
- OS: Red Hat Enterprise (32-bit)
- Apache, PHP, MySQL
- No of CPU: 8
- Memory: 32GB
- Space: 500GB SCSI

Second problem: The space for `/var` on DB server was only allocated to 20GB (not my fault). Normal utilization will consume around 80-90% of space. At 91-93%, the DB server will crash.

Normally, the site will work properly during the first 20 days of the month. The last 10 days, it will behave strangely such as:

- Product page is not viewable
- System will tend to go very slow
- at some stage, only homepage is accessible

The culprit is still unknown. In Mozilla Firefox it will return Connection Refused Error (111). On Google Chrome, it return Error Code 64:Host not available.

Some part of the log can be found here:
[system.log](http://www.postme.com.my/log/system.log)
[exception.log](http://www.postme.com.my/log/exception.log)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after lots of hours tweaking and trobleshooting this issue, I manage to find the culprit. It was

> AheadWorks Featured Product

plugin that was not compatible with the current Magento version. My method was to disable all plugins and revert to base theme. Thanks for all the insight and help in making Magento the best e-commerce platform (so far).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any log-files in *magento_installation_folder*/var/log/ ?

If website has lots of visits each day, it can insert many data into log tables.
Is there some logs cleaning configured on Magento?

Comment: This trick doesn't help. currently trying to figure out which extension may cause the issue

Answer (score 0):

1. try to clean unnecessarily log tables from db. take a look here - [clearing magento log data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638361/clearing-magento-log-data)
2. where do you hold your sessions? db or files? anyway, try to remove old sessions.
3. does your Mysql And Apache located on the same server? i suggest to split it into 2 servers. one for MySql and another one for Apache.
4. if you like, you can replace Apache with Nginx & php-fpm for better results.
5. if you have many pages - try to setup your full page cache extension to work with a memory key->value database. like redis.

good luck

Comment: 1.log were cleaned prior to posting this
2.session was set to db
3.Separate server but same config (refer to my question)
4.Not an option, as I already try to configure Magento to run on Nginx but it really pain in the a**
5.Redis may may be consider.

currently I'm trying to see if there is any extension caused the issue. the prime suspect was "Ahedworks Featured Product" extension